# C# MVC DateTime Picker Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, editor

So. If I have this in my model :

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
```

I get a nice date picker field when I invoke (can't select **time** though) :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

But, if I want to record something like date and starting **time** of an event :

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime Start { get; set; }
```

I get just a regular text field.

---

Also, I've just noticed that when I want to edit existing record, date is empty and has to be entered again even though all other fields are populated nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can also specify the datetime-local property in HTML.

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type="datetime-local" } })`

This is a pretty simple and easy way to get a date/time picker in your application.

Edit:
To get date/time to be set as the "default", you need a bit of jQuery as this isn't possible through `@Value` (that I know of). I use the following to set the date/time on forms.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var now = new Date();
    var day = (@Model.myDate.Day.ToString().Length != 2) ? "0" + @Model.myDate.Day : @Model.myDate.Day;
    var month = (@Model.myDate.Month.ToString().Length != 2) ? "0" + @Model.myDate.Month : @Model.myDate.Month;
    var today = @Model.myDate.Year + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
    $('#IdOfDateElement').val(today);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can save date-time as string in db or manipulate datetime value posted from UI from. See reference :
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
http://forums.asp.net/t/1975676.aspx?Tutorial+for+Adding+Datepicker+in+MVC+5